# cordova build android and ionic build android results in "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" after bluescreen

Tags: cordova, build, ionic-framework

I've built my app (cordova, ionic) using `cordova build android`. But while it was building I got a blue screen... Now I can't build the app, neither with `ionic build...` nor `cordova build...`

I've updated nodeJS, cordova, and ionic using npm.. but still get the same error. I even restored my daily backup from today morning, but the error remains.

Error:

```
C:\***\DEV\App\flugdeck>cordova build android

Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\***\DEV\App\flugdeck\hooks\before_prepare\01_jshint.js" "C:\***\DEV\App\flugdeck"

Linting www/js/app.js
File www/js/app.js has no errors.
-----------------------------------------
Linting www/js/config.js
File www/js/config.js has no errors.
-----------------------------------------
Linting www/js/controllers.js
File www/js/controllers.js has no errors.
-----------------------------------------
Linting www/js/controller_flightlog.js
File www/js/controller_flightlog.js has no errors.
-----------------------------------------
Linting www/js/controller_infotools.js
File www/js/controller_infotools.js has no errors.
-----------------------------------------
Linting www/js/controller_timetools.js
File www/js/controller_timetools.js has no errors.
-----------------------------------------
Linting www/js/directives.js
File www/js/directives.js has no errors.
-----------------------------------------
Linting www/js/factories.js
File www/js/factories.js has no errors.
-----------------------------------------
Linting www/js/filters.js
File www/js/filters.js has no errors.
-----------------------------------------
Linting www/js/mymodules.js
File www/js/mymodules.js has no errors.
-----------------------------------------
Linting www/js/services.js
File www/js/services.js has no errors.
-----------------------------------------
Linting www/js/templates.js
File www/js/templates.js has no errors.
-----------------------------------------

SyntaxError: Unexpected token
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Function.PlatformJson.load (C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\util\PlatformJson.js:35:21)
    at Object.handlePrepare (C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\prepare.js:48:37)
    at C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\prepare.js:105:21
    at Array.map (native)
    at C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\prepare.js:70:40
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
    at C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
```

Comment: You have syntax error in `json` configuration files when start to build

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a workaround:

1. Backup your complete app directory
2. Remove Android support from the app with the command `cordova platform remove android`
3. Delete the directory `root/platforms/android`
4. Add platform support with the command `cordova platform add android`
5. Run it once with the command `cordova run android`
6. Copy and overwrite the existing `AndroidManifest.xml` from your backup into the directory `root/platforms/android`
7. Run the command `cordova build android`