# Why am I getting cordova build android issue 'unexpected token'?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova

Hi I work with npm's plugin **cordova-plugin-calendar** and I get 'unexpected token' issue when type `cordova build android` . After debugging `cordova build -d` I get this message

> Executing "before_build"  hook for all plugins. Executing
>   "before_prepare"  hook for all plugins. Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at Function.PlatformJson.load (F:\win8 ja\OneDrive\Documents\magisterka IS\s 2\ZAI\projekt\cordova
>   projekt\project\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cor
>   dova-common\src\PlatformJson.js:35:21)
>       at new Api (F:\win8 ja\OneDrive\Documents\magisterka IS\s2\ZAI\projekt\cordo va
>   projekt\project\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:55:39)
>       at Object.getPlatformApi (C:\Users\Grzesiek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
>   \cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\platforms\platforms.js:59:23)
>       at C:\Users\Grzesiek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\c
>   ordova-lib\src\cordova\prepare.js:50:30
>       at Array.map (native)
>       at C:\Users\Grzesiek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\c
>   ordova-lib\src\cordova\prepare.js:48:39
>       at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Grzesiek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\no
>   de_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Grzesiek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
>   ules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Grzesiek\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
>   de_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)

Here is my cordova project zip http://www29.zippyshare.com/v/UC2hmFXn/file.html

Comment: I found a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671450/cordova-build-android-and-ionic-build-android-results-in-syntaxerror-unexpecte

Comment: but in my case doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative is a use of PhoneGap Build instead of Cordova CLI.
In my case **cordova-plugin-calendar** works